# onClick button to another activity crashes emulator

Tags: android-studio, buttonclick

I am completely new to Android studio. I have been trying to create a list of buttons which take the user to the different activities ("movieShowings" in this instance).

When I click on the button however the app crashes on the emulator.

Main Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

public void MovieShowings(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieShowings.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

layout Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/showingTimes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:text="Movie Showings"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:onClick="MovieShowings"/>
```

activity_Main

```
public class MovieShowings extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] foods = {"Bad Boys", "Purge", "Interstellar", "7 Pounds"};
    ListAdapter Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);
    ListView movieList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieList);
    movieList.setAdapter(Adapter);

    movieList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String food = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(MovieShowings.this, food, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

Error message

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.niallgrace.cinemaapp, PID: 6200
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.niallgrace.cinemaapp/com.example.niallgrace.cinemaapp.MovieShowings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.niallgrace.cinemaapp.MovieShowings.onCreate(MovieShowings.java:22)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)

Comment: There are many, many, many references to this here and on the greater web. What research have you done? What sorts of things do you find searching on that very common error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `View view` from the bracket of your method MovieShowings.
Also replace `this` in your method with `YourActivityName.this`

Edit 1:
As per your error logs, it looks like that something is wrong with listView in your activity in which you are switching too

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout file here `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and make sure that the ListView matches the id specified here `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.movieList);`. That would throw the exception if it fails to find the layout element.